# Instagram API randomly stopped fetching

Tags: javascript, api, limit, instagram

I just built something earlier today for testing/learning purposes (http://himynameismarvin.com/instahelp) and as you can see by visiting it, it IS loading the images requested from Instagram.

I moved on and started building something new (http://himynameismarvin.com/instabroken) with the EXACT same script. It was working all day as I was building, then RANDOMLY decided to not load the images. I first thought it was a limit on the API, but my first example still works, and I'm using the same client ID, auth code, etc.

Any reasons as to why this might be happening?

**FIXED**, but please see comments below

Comment: I have some pictures show up on both pages you linked to.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work for almost 3 hours, then when I decided to ask about it, it resumes working. If anyone could still shed some light as to why this happened/might happen again it would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You may be running into rate limits. From the docs at http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/

Limits
Be nice. If you're sending too many requests too quickly, we'll send back a 503 error code (server unavailable).

You are limited to 5000 requests per hour per access_token or client_id overall. Practically, this means you should (when possible) authenticate users so that limits are well outside the reach of a given user.

Comment: I am aware of the limits, this is why I posted 2 links, one was still working and one wasn't on the same Client ID and Auth Code, so limits couldn't have been a factor or they both should have stopped working.